# Получение ID другой страницы PHP

Tags: php, веб-программирование

Всем привет, у меня на сайте есть рабочая форма добавления записи (http://irbis.test000.ru/admin-news.php) и под ней список записей с возможностью редактирования. При нажатии на ссылку "редактировать" появляется форма редактирования записи, ее обработка происходит в файле `edit-news.php` вот его код:

```
<?php
require_once "functions/functions.php";
$news = getNews($_GET["id"]);
connectDB();
mysqli_query($mysqli, 'SET NAMES utf8');
if(!empty($_FILES['img']['tmp_name'])){
    $img = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['img']['tmp_name']));
}
else{
    echo 'Вставьте картинку';
}
if (!empty($_POST['title']) && !empty($_POST['desc']) && !empty($_POST['text'])){
$title = $_POST['title'];
$desc = $_POST['desc'];
$text = $_POST['text'];

$result = $mysqli->query("UPDATE `news` SET `title` = '$title', `desc` = '$desc', `text` = '$text', `img` = '$img' WHERE `id` = '$id'");
if ($result == true){
    echo "Информация занесена в базу данных";
}else{
    echo "Информация не занесена в базу данных";
}

}
else{
    echo'error';
}
echo $id;
echo $title;
closeDB();
?>
```

Проблема в том, что код не может получить ID записи и следовательно не заносит данные в БД, а если убрать из SQL запроса `WHERE`id` = '$id' то изменение записей применяются ко всем строкам в БД. Как получить ID записи из admin-news_edit.php чтобы использовать его в запросе файла edit-news.php?

Answer (score 1):

Когда формируете форму на странице admin-news_edit.php?id=85 добавьте в форму 
`<input type="hidden" value="85" name="id"/>` и вам в `$_POST['id']` придет этот id

либо пишите в форме `<form action="admin-news_edit.php?id=85" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">` тогда вы сможете вытащить id из параметра `$_GET['id']`

а если посмотреть по вашему коду то у вас $id нигде не объявлен

```
$id = (int) $_GET['id'];
```

и лучше использовать подготовленные запросы при записи в базу, иначе словите sql инъекцию

Comment: Как это может помочь при передаче ID со страницы admin-news_edit.php на edit-news.php? Возможно я непонятно объясняю, но знаний PHP не хватает даже на то чтобы сформулировать проблему

Comment: Решил проблему. Спасибо за ваше участие